# How will i make a decrypt function from encrypt function in c++?

Tags: c++, encryption

So i have a encrypt function

```
std::string encrypt(std::string text, int s)
{
    std::string result = "";

    // traverse text 
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        // apply transformation to each character 
        // Encrypt Uppercase letters 
        if (isupper(text[i]))
            result += char(int(text[i] + s - 65) % 26 + 65);

        // Encrypt Lowercase letters 
        else
            result += char(int(text[i] + s - 97) % 26 + 97);
    }

    // Return the resulting string 
    return result;
}
```

and could  used like this:

```
 std::string ans = "AABBCCDDEEFFGGH"
 std::time_t result = std::time(nullptr);
 DWORD Hours = ((result / 60) / 60) / ans.length();
 std::cout << "Output: " << encrypt(ans, Hours) << std::endl;
```

I tried making the decryption function but failed up miserably having the output as:

```
┐┐ªªºº¿¿⌐⌐¬¬½½¼
```

Could anyone help?

You guys asked for the decrypt function i tried to make, so here it is:

```
std::string decrypt(std::string encryptedtext, int s)
{
    std::string result;
    //RZHUPINVGIQZHXW
    for (int i = 0; i < encryptedtext.length(); i++)
    {
        if (isupper(encryptedtext[i]))
            result += char(int((65 - (encryptedtext[i] + 65 - s) % 26) + 65));
        else
            result += char(int((97 - (encryptedtext[i] + 65 - s) % 26) + 97));
    }
    return result;
}
```

i messed around with it a bit, and i ended up getting letters with circles on top

Comment: I think this is basically just a Caeser Cipher, right? The cool thing about that is that decrypting is just another Caeser Cipher - so if you encrypt by shifting 7 places, you decrypt by shifting 26-7=19 places.

Comment: Please provide the decrypt function.

Comment: If you want to know why your decrypt function does not work, you have show how that function looks like.

Comment: Look at what the value of `┐` is (probably 191 but it'll depend on your encoding/codepage), then compare it to the value you wanted (65 for `A` in ASCII). Then work out, mathematically, where you went wrong, based on your value of `s`. This is just maths!

Answer (score 0):

Your code currently treats lowercase letters and non-letters the same:

```
// Encrypt Uppercase letters 
if (isupper(text[i]))
  result += char(int(text[i] + s - 65) % 26 + 65);

// Encrypt Lowercase letters 
else
  result += char(int(text[i] + s - 97) % 26 + 97);
```

Your `else` handles both lowercase and other non-letter characters: `=?,&$` etc.  You need something more like:

```
// Encrypt Uppercase letters.
if (isupper(text[i])) {
  // Process uppercase letter.
  ### code here ###
}
// Encrypt Lowercase letters.
else if (islower(text[i])) {
  // Process lowercase letter.
  ### code here ###
}
// Handle non-letters.
else {
  // Process non-letter.
  ### code here ###
}
```